# Как сделать реверс слов в строке, но сохранить их положение?

Tags: java, строки

Возникли трудности при изучении java. Поставлена задача: "Дана строка. Вывести на экран строку со словами, которые записаны наоброт, но не изменив их порядок. Пример: 'Сегодня чудесная погода', вывести на экран 'Яндогес яанседуч адогоп'".

Вот что у меня получилось сделать:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Строка для которую нужно изменить
        String str3 = "Ut sit amet consequat nisl";
        //Разбитие строки по пробелу в массив
        String[] words = str3.split(" ");
        //Создание билдера строки для добавления слов
        StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder();


        for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
            //Два массива для реверса
            char[] tempCharArray = new char[words[i].length()];
            char[] charArray = new char[words[i].length()];

            //Разбить слово на буквы и поместить в массив
            for (int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); i++) {
                tempCharArray[j] = words[i].charAt(j);
            }
            //Реверс массива с буквами
            for (int k = 0; k< words[i].length(); k++){
                charArray[k] = tempCharArray[words[i].length() - 1 - k];
            }
            //Преобразование массива в строку
            String reverseWord = new String(charArray);
            //добавление той строки в билдер
            newStr.append(reverseWord);
        }
        //Вывод на екран
        System.out.println(newStr);
    }
}
```

Но код выводит с ошибкой

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
```

Скорее всего, что массиву words не объявлен размер по типу

```
String[] words = new String[array.length];
```

Но пока не представляю как грамотно исполнить подобную задачу. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Если мой вариант очень плох подскажите другой. Буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str3 = "Ut sit amet consequat nisl";
    String[] words = new StringBuilder(str3).reverse().toString().split(" ");
    StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) newStr.append(words[i]).append(" ");
    System.out.println(newStr);
}
```

Как-то сложно все, можно проще...

Comment: Вроде первый reverse лишний?

Comment: Там он всего один...

Comment: А, нет, всё понял.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо за ответ, ваш ответ мне импонирует более всех) То чего я искал. Спасибо еще раз, пожалуй так и сделаю

Comment: Не за что, обращайтесь))

Comment: Прикольно, не знал про reverse() у StringBuilder'a

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, в моём решении он тоже есть)

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, он к сожалению спрятался за горизонтальный скролл..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ну скролл же там не просто так болтается ;)

Answer (score 4):

У Вас в коде 1 опечатка:

```
for (int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); i++) { // i++ вместо j++
     tempCharArray[j] = words[i].charAt(j);
}
```

Ну и не хватает

```
newStr.append(" ");
```

в конце цикла

---

Вот класс целиком:

```html
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Строка для которую нужно изменить
        String str3 = "Ut sit amet consequat nisl";
        //Разбитие строки по пробелу в массив
        String[] words = str3.split(" ");
        //Создание билдера строки для добавления слов
        StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder();


        for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
            //Два массива для реверса
            char[] tempCharArray = new char[words[i].length()];
            char[] charArray = new char[words[i].length()];

            //Разбить слово на буквы и поместить в массив
            for (int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); j++) {
                tempCharArray[j] = words[i].charAt(j);
            }
            //Реверс массива с буквами
            for (int k = 0; k< words[i].length(); k++){
                charArray[k] = tempCharArray[words[i].length() - 1 - k];
            }
            //Преобразование массива в строку
            String reverseWord = new String(charArray);
            //добавление той строки в билдер
            newStr.append(reverseWord);
            newStr.append(" ");
        }
        //Вывод на екран
        System.out.println(newStr);
    }
}
```

Вот вариант со стримами:

```js
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str3 = "Ut sit amet consequat nisl";
        str3 = Stream.of(str3.split(" "))
                .map(Main::reverse)
                .reduce((a, w) -> a + " " + w).get();
        System.out.println( str3);
    }

    public static String reverse(String str){
        return str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                .reduce("", (s,c) -> c+s, (s1,s2) -> s2+s1);
    }
}
```

PS: Совет, научитесь пользоваться отладчиком

Comment: #facepalm, спасибо за помощь, пожалуй отдохну сегодня))))

Answer (score 3):

https://ideone.com/qtEDMo

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "Ut sit amet consequat nisl";
    System.out.println(StringReplacer.replace(s, Pattern.compile("\\w+"), m -> new StringBuilder(m.group()).reverse().toString()));
  }
}

class StringReplacer { // https://stackoverflow.com/q/43371521/4928642
  public static String replace(String input, Pattern regex, Function<Matcher, String> callback) {
    StringBuffer resultString = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(input);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
      regexMatcher.appendReplacement(resultString, callback.apply(regexMatcher));
    }
    regexMatcher.appendTail(resultString);

    return resultString.toString();
  }
}
```

PS: В очередной раз радуюсь, что я не пишу на джаве:

```js
var s = "Ut sit amet consequat nisl";
console.log(s.replace(/\w+/g, m => m.split("").reverse().join("")));
```

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, реально думал, что за минуту напишу ответ, но задолбался гуглить, как всё это делается (( Ни замены с коллбеком, ни нормального реверса строки. В C# вроде всё есть)

Comment: @Qwertiy так вот и я задолбался, спасибо за ответ)))

Comment: @Qwertiy дополнил свой ответ вариантом со стримами =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, эффективность хромает - квадратичная асимптотика из-за сложения строк при переворачивании слова. И вообще, второй раз плюсануть всё равно не могу)

Answer (score 0):

Как то так

```
public static String reverseWords(final String original)
  {
    StringBuilder reverseString = new StringBuilder();
        Arrays.stream(original.split(" ")).forEach(word -> {
            StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(word);
            reverseString.append(reverse.reverse().append(" "));
        });
        return reverseString.substring(0,reverseString.length()-1);
  }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]